# Composer executes without any output

Tags: composer-php

I'm running composer on Mac OS Yosemite. It worked well but suddenly I got no output at all (including any error).
For an example, when I run:

> **composer --version**

terminal executes that without any output. No error as well. It happens with all composer command options. I did Google search but without relevant results.
Any idea?

Comment: For more details, you can try higher verbosity `composer -vvv`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a reason. Timezone must be set in php.in (date.timezone = UTC). I'm not sure what update caused composer to stop working, but that has solved a problem).

Comment: Hey i have the same problem now on windows .. i went to php.ini and set date.timezone value to Africa/Cairo but nothing changed .. are you sure this is the solution because when i type composer nothing happen but a new line then after it new type command area